# Query Firestore by UserID and date range?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I need to query Firestore, but it keeps telling me I need an index. Problem is that isn't realistic, since EVERY user would require a custom index based on their UserId. For security, I can't allow anyone access unless `canAccess.${userID} == true` as in the example below. But if I were to take ALL items, and filter them by date client-side I would be fetching hundreds of thousands of items every time I change the date range, so it isn't practical.

```
this.db.collection('items')
       .where(`canAccess.${userId}`, '==', true)
       .where('date', '>=', startDate)
       .where('date', '<=', endDate);
```

How would one going about fetching only the items they are allowed to access, and only between the chosen date range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to restructure your documents in order to perform this query.  Consider putting the uids that can access the document in a field with a List type called `canAccess`.  Then query the list with [`array-contains`](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html) after you create an index on that field.

```
this.db.collection('items')
       .where('canAccess', 'array-contains', userId)
       .where('date', '>=', startDate)
       .where('date', '<=', endDate);
```

Comment: Oh I assumed querying an array would be just like querying an object in this situation (Would still need an index for array contents or something). Thanks! I'll give this a shot!